# Why is res.download() not working when passing in file path?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, https

Hello everyone I'm trying to create a feature to allow users to enter a file path and download it. I'm using a form with an input of type text to get the path. I'm using Node.js and Express router to handle to the get and post requests. For some reason my res.download isn't working.

```
router.get('/downloadFiles', (req, res, next) => {
  const filePath = req.query.filePath;
  res.download(filePath);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the files exist on the path and is the path correct?

Comment: Console.log(filePath) and check if the resource actually exists.

Comment: Also, res.redirect() after res.download() should not be working. Are you not getting a Header already sent error?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the
res.redirect('/');
Line it worked